# How do I specify how an object is converted to string to display it in a JavaFX TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, jodatime

I have a TableView with a couple of columns created with FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="logTable" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="timestampColumn" editable="false" text="Timestamp">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="timestamp"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn fx:id="actionColumn" editable="false" text="Action">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="action"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

I then have an object defined like this:

```
private ObservableList<LogEntry> log = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

which is set as the model for the TableView:

```
logTable.setItems(log);
```

The LogEntries look like this:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class LogEntry {
    private SimpleObjectProperty<DateTime> timestamp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private SimpleStringProperty action = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public LogEntry(String format, Object... args) {
        this.timestamp.setValue(new DateTime());
        String s = String.format(format, args);
        System.out.println(s);
        this.action.setValue(s);
    }

    public DateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp.getValue();
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action.getValue();
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I specify how the Jodatime DateTimes are converted into strings for displaying? I want to convert them using the current locale (but I want sorting on that column to still work).

Comment: OT: Are you tied to Java 7 or forced to use Joda Time for some other reason here? The Java 8 time API basically makes Joda Time redundant (it's based very heavily on Joda Time and the API is very similar). The [Joda Time home page](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) actually says: **"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."**

Comment: @James_D: I'm actually using Java 8. I didn't know about Java 8 making it redundant. I'll have to look into it. Thank you.

Comment: @Pablo The [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) project defining *java.time* is led by the same man who created *Joda-Time*, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen). The *java.time* classes are a complete re-write from scratch of *Joda-Time* using the lessons learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Joda Time but have done similar with LocalDateTime.

Here is an example of how that might work.

First you would need to expose the properties::

```
public class LogEntry {
    private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> timestamp = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private SimpleStringProperty action = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> timestampProperty() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }

    public final java.time.LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestampProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setTimestamp(final java.time.LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.timestampProperty().set(timestamp);
    }

    public final SimpleStringProperty actionProperty() {
        return this.action;
    }

    public final java.lang.String getAction() {
        return this.actionProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setAction(final java.lang.String action) {
        this.actionProperty().set(action);
    }
}
```

Then you set the cell factory and cell value factory:

```
dateTimeColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new LocalDateTimeTableCell<LogEntry>(true));
dateTimeColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().timestampProperty());
```

Create a Table Cell like this:

```
public class LocalDateTimeTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, LocalDateTime> {
    private final DateTimeFormatter myDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    private final DateTimeFormatter myDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    private final boolean showTime;

    public LocalDateTimeTableCell(boolean showTime){
        this.showTime = showTime;
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            // Format date.
            if(showTime) {
                setText(myDateTimeFormatter.format(item));
            }else {
                setText(myDateFormatter.format(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for with Joda time - but should give you direction.

Comment: I recommend allowing to pass the formatters to the cell in the constructor. You could still provide a no-args constructor using the the values you currently use. However providing a constructor passing those values would allow you to reuse the formatters for the whole column instead of creating one for every single cell instance...

Comment: What about making them static final?  Then the internal implementation is hidden and they would be class level?

Comment: Possible, but passing them to the constructor is more flexible, since you could pass different formats (e.g. for using "european" date format). Personally I'd prefer this and create static `forTableColumn` methods for creating cell factories (like it's done with other `TableCell` implementations). In such a method it would be easy to declare the formatters as local variables and use them in a lambda expression/anomymus class returned from the method.

Answer (score -1):

> using cell-factory to update the cell

```
private TableColumn<Customer, LocalDateTime> Col_date;
    Col_date.setCellFactory((TableColumn<LogEntry, LocalDateTime> param) -> {
        TableCell<LogEntry, LocalDateTime> cell = new TableCell<LogEntry, LocalDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(getDateTimeFormat(item,"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"));

                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    });


public static String getDateTimeFormat(LocalDateTime dateTime,String format) throws DateTimeParseException {
    return dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
}
```